# Ignore a condition is the values is not present in pandas

Tags: python, exception, key

Hi i have following code :

```
def label_exception (row):
   if row['Dividend with no set frequency'] >= 1 :
      return 'ExceptionCase'
   if (row['count'] != 12)  &  (row['Monthly dividend']  > 1) :
      return 'ExceptionCase '
   if (row['count'] != 4) & (row['Quarterly dividend'] > 1) :
      return 'ExceptionCase'
   if (row['count'] != 2) & (row['Semi-annual dividend'] > 1):
      return 'ExceptionCase'
   if (row['count']  != 1) & (row['Annual dividend'] > 1):
      return 'ExceptionCase'
   if row['Semi-annual dividend'] is not in :
   else:
        return 'NotanExceptionCase'

Final_Output['exception'] = Final_Output.apply (lambda row: label_exception(row), axis=1)
```

Now if any of the above row value is not present in the data frame its giving an Key error
What i am trying to do is if the value is not present it should ignore and continue to next condition  instead of giving an key error

How can this be put in place

Answer (score 0):

You should us try except, that is:

```
try:
   if row['something'] > something:
      return 'something'
except KeyError:
   pass
```

You should also check how to raise exceptions, rather than simply print them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

you should look into try and except, and error catching in python in general.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html